# Query the ids of every entry including a specified child key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given a database scheme like the following:

```
{
   "lessons": {
      "subjectId1": {
           "lessonId2": { ... },
           "lessonId4": { ... },
           "lessonId6": { ... }
      },
      "subjectId2": {
           "lessonId1": { ... },
           "lessonId3": { ... },
           "lessonId5": { ... },
           "lessonId7": { ... }
      }
   }
}
```

How do I retrieve the id(s) of any subject(s) that include a given lessonId?

I came up with a function like this:

```
    const refWithParent = database.ref("lessons");
    const snapshot = await refWithParent.orderByChild(lessonId).limitToLast(1).once("value");

    let firebaseId = null;
    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
        snapshot.forEach(entry => {
            firebaseId = entry.key;
            return true;
        });
    }
    return firebaseId;
```

This does work but I can't create an index in the database as the children are dynamically created.
Is there any easier way to retrieve the id?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to retrieve one index of any subject that contains a lesson with a specific id. If so, you can add a node "contains" to each subject into which you will put a key/value of the form: `lessonId: true`.

```
{
   "lessons":{
      "subjectId1":{
         "contains":{
            "lessonId2":true,
            "lessonId4":true,
            "lessonId6":true
         },
         "lessonId2":{ ... },
         "lessonId4":{ ... },
         "lessonId6":{ ... }
      },
      "subjectId2":{
         "contains":{
            "lessonId1":true,
            "lessonId3":true,
            "lessonId5":true,
            "lessonId7":true
         },
         "lessonId1":{ ... },
         "lessonId3":{ ... },
         "lessonId5":{ ... },
         "lessonId7":{ ... }
      }
   }
}
```

And then make a query (assuming **lessonID** is a variable in your code):

```
refWithParent.orderByChild(`contains/${lessonID)`).equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1).once('value');
```

and then check the obtained snaphost as follows:

```
if (snapshot.val() !== null)
{
   let subjectId = snapshot.key;
   //TODO something with subjectId...
}
```

*Note*, you must always add corresponding pair to "contains" node when you add a lesson to a subject. The same with removing.

*P.S.* If you want to obtain IDs of all subjects that contain given lesson, then simply remove `.limitToFirst(1)` from the query. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In Nosql like firebase you can denormalise or form your database as you want. I would advise that you make all your lesson names have a concatenation of it's subject when you creating them in order to avoid your querying of the database.
The codes below can help in getting a unique lesson id with a concatenation of the subject name before you create them.

```
 let newId = database.ref("lessons").ref.push().key; //<-- get a new unique id
 let newlessonname = 'Subject2_' + newId;
```

So your db would look like this

```
{
   "lessons": {
      "subjectId1": {
           "subjectId1_lessonId2": { ... },
           "subjectId1_lessonId4": { ... },
           "subjectId1_lessonId6": { ... }
      },
      "subjectId2": {
           "subjectId2_lessonId1": { ... },
           "subjectId2_lessonId3": { ... },
           "subjectId2_lessonId5": { ... },
           "subjectId2_lessonId7": { ... }
      }
   }
}
```

> Alternatively

You can include your Subjectid in the object of each lesson like this

```
{
   "lessons": {
      "subjectId1": {
           "lessonId2": {subjectid:"subjectId1" ... },
           "lessonId4": { ... },
           "lessonId6": { ... }
      },
      "subjectId2": {
           "lessonId1": { ... },
           "lessonId3": { ... },
           "lessonId5": { ... },
           "lessonId7": { ... }
      }
   }
}
```